# Attach and instantiate Service into Application.java

Tags: java, android, service

I am trying attach and instantiate a variable that is a Service, before start the first Activity.

I am trying this:

**Application.java**

```
public class ApplicationBase extends Application {

    public ServiceDoSport mServiceDoSport;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        startService(new Intent(this, ServiceDoSport.class));
        super.onCreate();
    }

}
```

**ServiceDoSport.java:**

```
public class ServiceDoSport extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // attach service to main application
        ApplicationBase mApplication = (ApplicationBase) getApplication();
        mApplication.mServiceDoSport = this;
    }
}
```

But the onCreate method of the first Activity is called before than Service has been attached and instantiated to ApplicationBase.

How I can do this?

What I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying attach and instantiate a variable that is a Service, before start the first Activity

You cannot guarantee that will happen. `startService()` is asynchronous, and you have no way to guarantee that it will start before an activity does.